# Convergence of sequences and limits

Tags: convergence-divergence

Let $(f_n)$ be the fibonacci sequence and let $x_n = \dfrac{f_{n+1}}{f_n}$. Given that $\lim_{n \to \infty}(x_n) = L$ exists, determine the value of $L$.

Comment: This appears to have been asked and answered here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/739229/fibonacci-sequence-golden-ratio

Answer (score 1):

**A start:** We have $f_{n+1}=f_n+f_{n-1}$. Divide both sides by $f_n$. We obtain $$x_n=1+\frac{1}{x_{n-1}}.$$