# convergence of a series by permuting its elements

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, divergent-series

Let $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} $  be a bijective function, the series $ \displaystyle \sum_ {n = 0}^{\infty} a_ {n} $ converges if and only if the series $ \displaystyle \sum_ {n = 0}^{\infty} a_ {f (n) }$ is convergent.

my attempt:

Since $f$ is bijective, the only thing it does is to permute the set $\mathbb{N}$, so if any of the series converges when the elements of $\mathbb{N}$ are perrmuted, their partial sums would continue to converge, therefore the proposition is true.

However in my class they said that the statement is false so I tried to find a counterexample, but I could not find it. I am really confused. Any help that makes me see that the proposition is true or false would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ converges conditionally, for every $r\in\Bbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$ there is a bijection $f:\Bbb{N}\to\Bbb{N}$ s.t $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{f(n)}=r$, so the statement is false.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rearrangement of Alternating Harmonic Series to be Infinity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2969898/rearrangement-of-alternating-harmonic-series-to-be-infinity)