# Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac1n$ is convergent but not unconditionally convergent

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

If $\left\{f_k\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence in a normed vectore space $X$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} f_{\sigma(k)}$ is convergent for all permutations $\sigma$, we say that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} f_k$ is unconditionally convergent.

I would like to prove that the following series
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac1n$$
is not unconditionally convergent.

**My attempt:**
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac1n=\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{2k} \frac{1}{2k}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{2k-1} \frac{1}{2k-1}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2k}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2k-1}$$
But $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2k}$ is divergent.

P.S. This question follows my attempt to find a sequence $\left\{a_k\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ of real numbers for which $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k$ is convergent but not unconditionally convergent, to understand the definition of unconditionally convergence.

Comment: $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{2k} \frac{1}{2k}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{2k-1} \frac{1}{2k-1}$ is not a rearrangement of the original series. (If you are not convinced: Try to write down the definition of the permutation $\sigma$.)

Comment: Can you use that (in finite dimensional spaces) unconditional convergence is equivalent to absolute convergence?

Comment: Hint: Consider large blocks of even terms followed by single odd terms.

Comment: See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2969898/42969

Comment: @MartinR thank you, the last comment helped me to understand!

Answer (score 1):

For the convergence, you can use the Leibnitz Test. We consider $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$ . The $(a_n)$ is a decreasing sequence, and $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=0.$ Thus, we have by Leibnitz Test that the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{1}{n}$ is convergent.

For the absolute convergence you can see that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n|$ does not converge.

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{N}(-1)^n\frac{1}{n}$ does exists because
$$
     (-1)^n\frac{1}{n}+(-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{n+1} \\
   = (-1)^n\left[\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right] \\
   = (-1)^n\left[\frac{1}{n(n+1)}\right]
$$
However, the series is not absolutely convergent.