# Is the Fibonacci sequence exponential?

Tags: exponential-function, fibonacci-numbers

I could not find any information on this online so I thought I'd make a question about this.

If we take the Fibonacci sequence $F_n = F_{n-1} + F_{n-2}$, is this growing exponentially? Or perhaps if we consider it as a function $F(x) = F(x-1) + F(x-2)$, is $F(x)$ an exponential function?

I know Fibonacci grows rather quick, but is there a proof that shows whether it is exponential or not?

Comment: Look at Binet's formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Relation_to_the_golden_ratio

Comment: Yes, of course, it is extremely close to $C \varphi^n \; , \;$ where $\varphi = \frac{1 + \sqrt 5}{2}$ and $C$ is a constant

Comment: @J.G. yah, I lost my focus...

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The Fibonacci Sequence does not take the form of an exponential $b^n$, but it does exhibit exponential growth. Binet's formula for the $n$th Fibonacci number is
$$F_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\bigg(\frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}\bigg)^n-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\bigg(\frac{1-\sqrt 5}{2}\bigg)^n$$
Which shows that, for large values of $n$, the Fibonacci numbers behave approximately like the exponential $F_n\approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\phi^n$.

Comment: +1 for a clear and succinct answer. I might write $F_n \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \phi^n$ for precision.

Comment: @Travis Fair enough. :)

Comment: "does not take the form of an exponential b^n, but it does exhibit exponential growth" Is it possible? I thought the two statements ("it takes the form of an exponential b^n" and "it exhibits exponential growth") were synonyms.

Comment: @ThePhi By "exponential growth", I mean that the sequence is asymptotically $\sim \beta\cdot\alpha^n$ for some $\alpha,\beta>0$, but it is not *precisely equal* to $\beta\cdot\alpha^n$ for any $\alpha,\beta>0$. In this case, $\alpha=\phi$ and $\beta=1/\sqrt{5}$.

Comment: I would understand exponential growth as $f(n)$ is both growing and $f(n) = Θ(e^n)$.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming

- $F_n = F_{n-1} + F_{n-2}$
- $F_n > F_{n-1}$
- $F_{n-1} > F_{n-2}$

$=>$

Start with $F_n = F_{n-1} + F_{n-2}$, and make the right side bigger by replacing $F_{n-2}$ with $F_{n-1}$

$F_n < F_{n-1} + F_{n-1}$

$=>$

$F_n < 2F_{n-1}$

$=>$

$F_n < 2^n$

So the fibonacci sequence, one item at a time, grows more slowly than $2^n$.

But on the other hand every 2 items the Fibonacci sequence more than doubles itself:

$(1) F_n = F_{n-1} + F_{n-2}$

$(2) F_{n-1} = F_{n-2} + F_{n-3}$

$=>$

Replace $F_{n-1}$ in $(1)$ with $F_{n-1}$ from $(2)$

$F_n = 2F_{n-2} + F_{n-3}$

$=>$

Because $F_{n-3}$ is greater than zero, we can drop it from the right side, and that makes the right side smaller than the left.

$F_n > 2F_{n-2}$

$=>$

$F_n > 2^{n/2}$

$F_n > (2^{1/2})^n$

$F_n > \sqrt{2}^n$

Because the Fibonacci sequence is bounded between two exponential functions, it's effectively an exponential function with the base somewhere between `1.41` and `2`.

${1.41}^n$ < $F_n < 2^n$

That base ends up being the golden ratio. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1201069/62698